Poor CLS score in Google Search Console but not Cloudflare or Lighthouse
my site mojiedit.com) has a poor CLS score (> 2.5) when looking at core web vitals in search console for mobile only. However, when I look at the mobile stats in the cloudflare speed test or go to my chrome browser and use Lighthouse my CLS is great. What am I looking at wrong? I am not sure what more I can do. I have optimized everything I can think of and use cloudflare as my cdn and am using wp rocket.
A good CLS score in google core web vitals for my site mojiedit.com

Looking at your real-user data in PageSpeed Insights, I can see a CLS score of 0.27 for your home page and 0.34 for the website as a whole:

Scrolling down to the diagnostic data from Lighthouse, it's only seeing a CLS score of 0.008 in synthetic testing:

This can happen when CLS issues arise as a result of user interactions. Synthetic tests don't interact with the page like a real user would, so they don't incur the same layout shifts and you'll see low scores like this. However, users are experiencing UX issues, so there is definitely something worth investigating.
This scenario is explained in the Optimize CLS docs, which also describes the next steps to measure post-load CLS locally and in the field to help you diagnose the source of the layout shifts.
